# How collapse rows based on repeated column value

Tags: google-sheets

e.g.

How do I **collapse** this

```
0 a 0 0 
0 a 0 0 
0 b 0 0
0 b 0 0
```

into this

```
0 a 0 0 
0 b 0 0
```

Which I can **expand** into the former

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns are A:D please try:

```
=unique(A:D)
```